# Understanding MIPS pipeline registers

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

I think im missing something about the pipeline registers. I do understand the functionallity of them (for the most part), but what i dont understand, and what i cant seem to find any good info about, is how they are implemented in the CPU. Are they a part of the register file, as in are some of the registers in the register file dedicated as pipeline registers? Or are they separate elements of the CPU (different hardware)?

From the info i've found it seems like they are registers in the register file, but does not that mean that data is written to and read from the register file for every stage of the pipeline? Which then would require a lot of inputs for the register file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but what are the pipeline registers? The latches/flip-flops between pipeline stages (i.e. those boxes needed to buffer information)? Usually the real details of the implementations are left unspecified. I believe they are sparse components though as they need to be accessed concurrently with the real register file.

Comment: Indeed, what do you mean by pipeline registers?

Comment: @MargaretBloom yeah im thinking about the registers used to hold information between pipeline stages, often called the IF/ID, ID/EX, EX/MEM and MEM/WB registers.

Comment: The registers between pipeline stages are simple flip-flops. They have nothing to do with the register file.